# How to stream mp3 audio from YouTube using python only with name of song

Tags: python, audio, pytube

i'm trying to create a virtual assistant.

One of the features i would like for my personal assistant to have is the ability to stream or download YouTube videos, in audio mp3 format.

So for example, i would be able to say 'Play Hello by Adele' and it would play the audio of the song.

I've got the whole virtual assistant part down, i'm just struggling on making it useful. I am creating the virtual assistant on my Raspberry pi using python. As you can see i have already started trying to code the whole music section, but i'm not able to figure out the YouTube par

I hope some of what I've done so far has been useful

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/result?ssearch_query=Hello+by+Adele")
t=yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
t[0].download(path)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Your posted code has a lot of overhead for the problem at hand: if your only current trouble is the YouTube part, then most of the previous code should be replaced by a a straight assignment, such as `yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='Hello by Adele'")`.  Then we need to requisite description of what's wrong with the current code.

Comment: I apologise Prune, i will shorten the code down and re-upload.